# How to get CRM 2013 Online Database schema

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

How can i get database schema for my Dynamics CRM 2013 Online? Is it possible in CRM 2013 online? If it is possible to get database schema, can you tell me any procedure?

Comment: As far as I know there is not a way to get database schema for CRM online as we have no access to database for online CRM ORGs.

Comment: ok. is there any better way to get schema kind of thing.  i want to present my database schema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quicker option that doesn't require getting a backup of the database is to use the XRMtoolbox available at http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com and use the Metadata Doc Generator tool.  That allows you to retrieve the Metadata and select all or some entities and various options for those entities and to save the output to a Word document or an Excel document.  While maybe not technically a database schema, it allows you to see even more information at a glance than you would see in the database schema because you can see things like if an attribute is available for Advanced find and which form or forms it is located on.

Another option is to install a local copy of Microsoft CRM that is the same version as the online version and to export the customizations and solutions from the CRM online version and then import them to the local CRM install.  This will give your local database the same schema as what exists in CRM online and you can either view the schema in SQL server management studio or other SQL database schema generation tools.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Chad Rexin, Tool worked for me. i got a document to represent CRM Schema. Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 2):

You can [request a copy of your Dynamics CRM organization database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127043%28v=crm.6%29.aspx) from CRM Online support. Then you'll have your Dynamics CRM database and you can restore it to a local SQL Server. If you don't already have a SQL instance you can use the Developer edition, if you have access, or use a trial.

Be sure to ask which version of SQL Server you need to use to restore.

> To receive a copy of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online SQL Server
>   database, contact Live Customer Service by calling 1-877-CRM-CHOICE
>   (1-877-276-2464) Monday-Friday, 8:00 A.M.-8:00 P.M. Central Time
>   (UTC-6) in the U.S. and in Canada.
>
> Restore the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online SQL Server database
>
> The backup of your Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online SQL Server database
>   must be restored by using a server running the same (or a newer)
>   version of Microsoft SQL Server as is running in Microsoft’s data
>   centers. At the time of this writing, Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online
>   data centers are running SQL Server 2008.